# coffee-script loop efficiency

Tags: coffeescript

super simple coffeescript question

```
circles = []
for coordinate, i in coordinates
    circles[i] = new MakeCircle(cnBlue, coordinate.x, coordinate.y, 16, 8, 0, theCanvas.ctx)
```

This works. But I know that with the syntax candy there is probably and even more coffeescriptish way to write this. Is there a way to write this without using the `i`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical CoffeeScript way is to use a for comprehension, which will return an array:

```
circles = for coordinate in coordinates
  new MakeCircle(cnBlue, coordinate.x, coordinate.y, 16, 8, 0, theCanvas.ctx)
```

Or, on one line:

```
circles = (new MakeCircle(cnBlue, coordinate.x, coordinate.y, 16, 8, 0, theCanvas.ctx) for coordinate in coordinates)
```

See [Loops and Comprehensions](http://coffeescript.org/#loops):

> Note how because we are assigning the value of the comprehensions to a variable in the example above, CoffeeScript is collecting the result of each iteration into an array.

Comment: Yeah I checked the official documentation, had a really hard time understanding it. Thanks for informing me.

Comment: The parentheses are unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
circles.push(new MakeCircle(cnBlue, coordinate.x, coordinate.y, 16, 8, 0, theCanvas.ctx))
```

;)

Answer (score 1):

More "coffeescriptish" is writing it on one line :

```
circles = []
circles[i] = new MakeCircle(cnBlue, coor.x, coor.y, 16, 8, 0, theCanvas.ctx) for coor, i in coordinates
```

you could remove `i` when using push

```
circles = []
mc = (x,y) -> new MakeCircle cnBlue,x,y,16,8,0,theCanvas.ctx
circles.push mc(coor.x,coor.y) for coor in coordinates
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [jQuery map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```
circles = jQuery.map(coordinates, 
    (coordinate) -> new MakeCircle(cnBlue, coordinate.x, coordinate.y, 16, 8, 0, theCanvas.ctx)
)
```

I've never actually written CoffeeScript before, so apologies if that doesn't compile as is. This is definately a more "functional" style way of doing what you want, which I identify with modern javascript.

Comment: In modern browsers/javascript the `map` method is also available on `array` objects.